# Outbound link doesn't work

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I have three divs lined up horizontally. Each act as a button. When you click on them another div underneath them displays a different image. When you hover over that image another div slides up with a link to a different website.

The issue is when I click on the second or third button and then click on the outbound link which slides up in the div underneath them, the image of that div returns to it's default image rather than taking me to the website the link is linking me to.

I've tried putting this in a JSFiddle but it just won't display right for demonstration.

Here is the site: no longer available - click on 'Work' and you will see the 3 div buttons.

How do I get the link to not return the default image and instead just send me to the website it is linking to?

Here is the code for that section of the site:

**HTML**

```
<section class="top" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
        <section id="w">
            <div class="title">My Work</div>
                <div id="workSamples">
                    <a id="button1" href="#w" tabindex="1"><div class="slideUp"><img src="_images/work/sample01.jpg"></div></a>
                    <a id="button2" href="#w" tabindex="2"><div class="slideUp"><img src="_images/work/sample02.jpg"></div></a>
                    <a id="button3" href="#w" tabindex="3"><div class="slideUp"><img src="_images/work/sample03.jpg"></div></a>
                    <div id="content">
                        <div id="default"><img src="_images/absolutebeauty.jpg"><a href="http://www.absolutebeauty.ie" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Absolute Beauty<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>
                        <div id="absol"><img src="_images/absolutebeauty.jpg"><a href="http://www.absolutebeauty.ie" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Absolute Beauty<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>                                      
                        <div id="best"><img src="_images/bestacoustic.jpg"><a href="http://www.bestacousticguitarguide.com" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Best Acoustic Guitar Guide<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>
                        <div id="engage"><img src="_images/engagement.jpg"><a href="http://www.engagementringshq.com" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Engagement Rings HQ<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#workSamples {
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
}
#button1 {
    width:300px;
    height:236px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 20px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); 
}
#button2 {
    width:300px;
    height:236px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 20px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); 
}
#button3 {
    width:300px;
    height:236px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 20px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); 
}
.slideUp {
    width:300px;
    height:236px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slideUp img {
    height:auto;
    -webkit-transition: margin 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin 1s ease;
    -o-transition: margin 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: margin 1s ease;
    transition: margin 1s ease;
}
.slideUp img:hover {
    margin-top: -236px;
}

#button1:focus~#content #default,
#button2:focus~#content #default,
#button3:focus~#content #default,
#button4:focus~#content #default {display:none;}

#button1:focus~#content div:nth-child(2),
#button2:focus~#content div:nth-child(3),
#button3:focus~#content div:nth-child(4),
#button4:focus~#content div:nth-child(5) {display:block;}

#content {
    width:940px; 
    height:307px;
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    overflow:hidden;
    background:red;
}

.caption {
    width:920px;
    margin:auto;
    height:40px;
    background:#694264;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-out;  
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-out;  
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-out;  
    transition:all .3s ease-out;  
    left:0;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#content:hover .caption {
    -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);  
    -o-transform:translateY(-100%);  
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);  
    transform:translateY(-100%);  
}

#absol,#best,#engage {display:none;}

#absol:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: U have unclosed elements near your `</section>` and double class attributes in your HTML. Fix your HTML and it will work. See : http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liddily.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on a thumbnail image, the preview image and caption revert to the defaults every time you click away from the thumbnail. This is because you're using `:focus` to change CSS properties. Once the focus from the thumbnail is lost, everything goes back to normal.

I haven't tested this out but I think it should work. It uses a bit of JavaScript.

Edited HTML:

```
<section class="top" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
        <section id="w">
            <div class="title">My Work</div>
                <div id="workSamples">
                    <a id="absolButton" href="#w" tabindex="1" onclick="switchTab(this.id);"><div class="slideUp"><img src="_images/work/sample01.jpg"></div></a>
                    <a id="bestButton" href="#w" tabindex="2" onclick="switchTab(this.id);"><div class="slideUp"><img src="_images/work/sample02.jpg"></div></a>
                    <a id="engageButton" href="#w" tabindex="3" onclick="switchTab(this.id);"><div class="slideUp"><img src="_images/work/sample03.jpg"></div></a>
                    <div id="content">
                        <div id="defaultContent"><img src="_images/absolutebeauty.jpg"><a href="http://www.absolutebeauty.ie" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Absolute Beauty<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>
                        <div id="absolContent"><img src="_images/absolutebeauty.jpg"><a href="http://www.absolutebeauty.ie" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Absolute Beauty<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>                                      
                        <div id="bestContent"><img src="_images/bestacoustic.jpg"><a href="http://www.bestacousticguitarguide.com" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Best Acoustic Guitar Guide<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>
                        <div id="engageContent"><img src="_images/engagement.jpg"><a href="http://www.engagementringshq.com" target="_blank"><div class="caption">Engagement Rings HQ<br><u>Visit Site</u></div></a></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</section>
```

Add this JavaScript:

```
var lastClicked;

function switchTab(id) {
    document.getElementById("defaultContent").style.display = "none";
    if (lastClicked != null) {
        document.getElementById(lastClicked + "Content").style.display = "none";
    }
    lastClicked = id;
    document.getElementById(id + "Content").style.display = "block";
}
```

Remove this CSS:

```
#button1:focus~#content #default,
#button2:focus~#content #default,
#button3:focus~#content #default,
#button4:focus~#content #default {display:none;}

#button1:focus~#content div:nth-child(2),
#button2:focus~#content div:nth-child(3),
#button3:focus~#content div:nth-child(4),
#button4:focus~#content div:nth-child(5) {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: block;` for `a`

like

```
a {
display: block;
}
```

Reason: You are inserting Div inside `a` tag, By deafault `a` tag is inline. So you should change to `block`